# why apache shiro WildcardPermisssion object not work in version 1.2.0

Tags: shiro

I will use WildcardPermission in my code. I use it Similar following code:

```
getSubject().isPermitted(new WildcardPermission("a:b:*"));
getSubject().isPermitted(new WildcardPermission("a:b"));
getSubject().isPermitted(new WildcardPermission("a:b:c,d"));
getSubject().isPermitted(new WildcardPermission("a:b:c"));
getSubject().isPermitted(new WildcardPermission("a:b:d"));
```

The first 3 lines return false but lines 4 and 5 return true. I use apache shiro 1.2.0.
Have i any mistake? Do you have any solution for it?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried 1.2.3?

Comment: Well then try 1.2.3, it might contain bugfixes

Comment: in the now i test it with 1.2.3 but there is not any change.

Comment: Sorry, not a bug, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually do is query with strings that are used to **declare** permissions.

Taking your comment into account, the permissions declaration whould be something like:

```
[role]
x = a:b:c,d,e
```

Now the role x declares that it has permission on a:b:c, a:b:d and a:b:e.

Those are the values you can check permissions on. You can't check on wildcards as those are only used in **declaring** permissions.
So query on a:b:* or a:b:c,d will **never** work.

Query on a:b would work if you have declared it specifically in your shiro.ini.

So the only thing you can query on is a:b:c, a:b:d and a:b:e.

To give another example. User x can have the right to print anything, but user y only print on epson. 
You declare the right for user x as: print:* and for user y as print:epson.

Now for user x print:epson and print:brother will return true, but for user y only print:epson will return true and print:brother will return false.

So you declare that some role/user is allowed anything below a:b by using a:b, or a:b:*, but the actual action you query should be specific, so that is why only a:b:c and a:b:d return true.

Comment: thanks for time that you spend for my problem. i read your answer several time. but i cann't understand where is my problem. can you explain it for me with simpler language? my user can have permission like a:b:c - a:b:d - a:b:e - a:b:f. no body have permission a:b or a:c or anything else. thanks

Comment: tried to be more specific, let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: is the answer sufficient? if so accept, otherwise let me know